# Spinners, why different gap and wrong values returned

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

Problem: I have two spinners with different values in them. However, when watching them in the emulator or app, they both have a different "gap" between their items displayed on the screen. And when I try to send the values from my activity to another, I always get the wrong value for spinner 1.

Spinner 1:
[image]

Spinner 2:
[image]

String arrays:

```
    <string-array name="lage">
    <item>--Välj läge--</item>
    <item>Kök</item>
    <item>Badrum</item>
    <item>Hall</item>
    <item>Garderob</item>
    <item>Balkong</item>
    <item>Sovrum</item>
    <item>Vardagsrum</item>
    <item>Förråd</item>
    <item>Allmäna utrymmen</item>
    <item>Övrigt</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Fel">
    <item>--Välj läge--</item>
    <item>Vattenläcka</item>
    <item>Ventilation</item>
    <item>Fönster</item>
    <item>Avlopp</item>
    <item>Elfel</item>
    <item>Vitvaror</item>
    <item>Golv</item>
    <item>Vägg</item>
    <item>Övrigt</item>
</string-array>
```

Implementation of spinner adapters for simple dropdown items:

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.lage,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Fel,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    input1 = spinner1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    input2 = spinner2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

Button passing the values to the next activity:

```
buttonNasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), step2Fel.class);
            intent.putExtra("testX", input1);
            intent.putExtra("testY",input2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

input 1 and 2 are global "private static String" values.

Layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Located?"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/lage_spinner"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sqare_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Problem?"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/small_spinner"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sqare_frame" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have the first Java code snippet been pasted in correctly? As a side-note, you can use pairs of triple backticks to format code.

Comment: You can use various methods for checking what the values of your variables are, such as debug-printing like `System.out.println()`, logging the values using Logcat, and also the debugger built into Android Studio. As a side-note, avoiding global mutable variables is often a good idea.

Comment: Yes, but when I use system.out.println or send it to next activity the values of spinner 1 is always wrong, and the values of spinner 2 is always correct in the output. It's strange since they're implemented in the same way.

Comment: I have just updated my answer. As a side-note, you can use pairs of single backticks to format inline code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question reg. `setOnItemSelectedListener`

The problem seems to be that you use a single implementation for setting the global variables, and that means that they both get overwritten with the same value whenever an item in either list is selected.

### Option 1

If you use two separate implementations, that each only updates the corresponding variable, it should work as far as I can tell.

You can for instance use a new `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` in each of the calls to `setOnItemSelectedListener`, similar to how you do it with `setOnClickListener`.

One way that it might look is as follows (just a sketch, I very much prefer to teach people how to fish instead of giving them fish :) ):

```java
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.lage,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public onItemSelected(...) {...}
    @Override
    public onNothingSelected(...) {...}
});

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.Fel,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public onItemSelected(...) {...}
    @Override
    public onNothingSelected(...) {...}
});
```

### Option 2

An alternative approach is to differentiate in your current `onItemSelected` implementation which of the spinners it is and therefore which global variable should be updated, possibly testing with something like `parent == spinner1`, though I haven't checked this snippet.

## Question reg. gap between items

I think I know what it is now, in:

```java
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.Fel,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

the call to `setDropDownViewResource` should be to `adapter2`, not `adapter`. That is a very common and very easy mistake to make, I use the following approach to avoid making such mistakes myself:

```java
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        R.array.Fel,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

That way, the local variable `adapter2` is only available in the scope that it is relevant for. If you use the same block for the equivalent part for `adapter`, the compiler will complain when accidentally using `adapter` when `adapter2` should be used.

Comment: How would this look "code-wise"? Kind of confused on how to actually "do it" with the adapterview.onitemselectedlisteners. .

Comment: @RobinSvensson I have updated the answer with a code sketch as well as a second option. The second option might be much less verbose and closer to your current implementation.

Comment: @RobinSvensson I just changed the last snippet from `view == spinner1` to `parent == spinner1`, I haven't checked whether it is correct or not though.

Comment: The most simple solution out of your two options was the second one to be honest. It works perfectly fine with if statements. Now my only consern is why there is a "gap" when displaying the items in spinner 1, but not in spinnder 2. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @RobinSvensson The second option only occurred to me afterwards, it is indeed simpler. Reg. the gap, I wonder whether it might be something in the layout XML. Could you add the relevant layout XML to the question, such that I can have a look?

Comment: I added the xml.

Comment: @RobinSvensson I think I figured it out and added it to the answer, I also included the approach I use myself for avoiding that specific type of mistake.

Comment: Thanks a million, it all worked flawlessly now! Also thank you for the great tips which will help me evolve as a programmer as well.

Comment: @RobinSvensson I am very happy to help, and you're welcome :).